# Use ID of a tag for JQuery delegate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, delegates

I am using the [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) function of JQuery to attach an event to a tag. I have the following code:

```
<div><g id="a_abc"><a xlink:href=" " xlink:title="&lt;TABLE&gt;"> 
<text text-anchor="start" x="59.1729" y="-35.4537" font-family="font-awesome" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000"></text>
</a> 
</g></div>
```

I want to bind a delegate to the `text` part in the `g` tag, something like that:

```
$("div").delegate("g.a_abc", "click",function(){
        ...
    });
```

Is there a way to do that via the `id` attribute or must we have a `class` attribute? Because the above code does not work. Setting the selector to the `class` attribute makes the javascript code working.

Comment: Did you try "g#a_abc"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) like any other. So yes, you can do

```
$("div").delegate("#a_abc", "click", function() {
    // ...
});
```

(Or `g#a_abc` if you want to ignore an element with `id="a_abc"` if it isn't a `g` element.)

---

Side note: [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) has been superceded by [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for some years now, and is deprecated in v3.0. The `on` syntax reverses the selector and event:

```
$("div").on("click", "#a_abc", function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `<text>` tag to the selector and use the id if that's what you want

```js
$("div").delegate("#a_abc text", "click", function() {
     console.log(this)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <g id="a_abc">
    <a xlink:href=" " xlink:title="&lt;TABLE&gt;">
      <text text-anchor="start" x="59.1729" y="-35.4537" font-family="font-awesome" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000"></text>
    </a>
  </g>
</div>
```